# Removing Grunt from project for backup

Tags: gruntjs

For some reason i need to remove [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) form my project.My Internet connection is very slow and i need to backup my project and save project to [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com). Grunt make my project size bigger than i can upload project to internet. how to remove or skip grunt directory for backuping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.    You only the **"Gruntfile"**
Grunt application shouldn't be installed in the project folder anyway,  but globally:  `npm install -g grunt-cli`   *( -g == global )*